Flutter: How to make curve listview
I want to make a curved list item but it doesn't work as expected

I've tried ListWheelScrollView and circle_wheel_scroll package. Basically, I can create the design I want. But problem:

I can't tap on each element
I update transform rotate for each item when onSelectedItemChanged trigger, this makes scroll action is not smooth


 **Can you please try this.**

 Transform.rotate(
    angle: 35 * (3.14159 / 90),
    child: Container(
    height: 120,
    width: 100,
    color: Colors.pink,
        ),
      ),
   const SizedBox(height: 50),
   Container(
   height: 100,
   width: 120,
   color: Colors.pink,
   ),
   const SizedBox(height: 50),
   Transform.rotate(
   angle: 35 * (3.14159 / 90),
   child: Container(
   height: 120,
   width: 100,
   color: Colors.pink,
      ),
    ),

and are you using listview so manage on index.


It's a list with unstable item count. Example always 3 items are visible, group1 with index 0, 1, 2. How to set transform for items with index 2, 3, 4 to make them will replace exactly position of group1's items. I think it's too complicated for me now

are u manage in listview.builder ?

Yes, I still am trying use ListView and ScrollView

@KienVu could you share your solution, if you came up with an one, please?

@Liliia I didn't have much time so I used native code
